# bower install ECMDERR error - yo angular generator

Tags: angularjs, git, bash, bower

I am using yeoman's angular generator to scaffold an angular project on my windows 7 machine.

After the generator is done. I run the command 'bower install' and get this error :

[git bash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdy8P.png)

Here are the things I've tried so far :

1. Running ' git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "git://" ' and then running 'bower install' from git bash.
2. Setting up Git SSh keys correctly.
3. clean bower and npm cache. Reinstalling yeoman generators.

Nothing has worked for me so far. Anyone else managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the command line as administrator.